# Date/Time Enter a Valid Date/Time Form validation

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-views

When submitting a form I keep getting Enter a valid date/time

The code

forms.py

```
class LessonsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
    model = models.Lessons
    # datetime-local is a HTML5 input type, format to make date time show on fields

    widgets = {
      'start_of_lesson': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
      'end_of_lesson': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
    }

    fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LessonsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # input_formats to parse HTML5 datetime-local input to datetime field
        self.fields['start_of_lesson'].input_formats = ['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M']
        self.fields['end_of_lesson'].input_formats = ['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M']
```

settings.py

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%d/%m/%Y",
                "%d-%m-%Y",
                '%Y-%m-%d',
                '%Y/%m/%d',
                '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',
                '%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M',
                '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M',
                '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',
                '%d/%m/%YT%H:%M',
                '%d-%m-%YT%H:%M',]

      DATE_FORMAT = "d/m/Y"
      DATETIME_FORMAT = "d/m/Y H:i"
      TIME_FORMAT = "H:M"
```

I feel like I have messed around with the input formats everywhere and changed them to everything but it just won't validate when I save the form

```
 start_of_lesson = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y'], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg','type':'datetime-local'}))
```

Is an example of something I have tried.

EDIT:
models.py

```
class Lessons(models.Model):
type_of_lesson = models.CharField("Lesson Type", max_length=128)
description = models.TextField()
attendees = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="attendee_users")
max_capacity = models.IntegerField()
teacher = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="teaching_user",limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True})
start_of_lesson = models.DateTimeField()
end_of_lesson = models.DateTimeField()
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Comment: Could you post your `models.py` as well?

Comment: Updated to include models, I believe I have solved this by adding DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS into the settings file, but I will leave the question open to see if there is a better way of doing this.